# MOV_RESAVE_LARGER Error Loading Apple App Preview Video

Tags: ios

Got the following error loading an app preview, and that's all they gave. Didn't get a single hit anywhere on google explaining the error. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a different format size.  Handbrake was automatically scaling a 1200 x 1600 to 1200 x 1080, and I didn't notice.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain it a bit more clearly?

Comment: Yes, for me it just meant that the size was wrong.  Needs to be 1200x1600.